# How to force energy saver mode in Chromium-based browsers?

Tags: google-chrome

Chromium has a nice feature called [image: Energy Saver]

Unfortunately, it forces me to select either to turn on when my battery is 20% or lower, or when the computer is unplugged.

I'm on my laptop on the go, charging the device with an external power bank, thus my device is not "unplugged". Obviously, I still want to use Energy Saver, because the energy is limited from the power bank.

How to force-enable Battery Saver?

I use Arc, btw.

Comment: How exactly is the power from the power bank limited? If your laptop is plugged in it should be running at the highest performance mode.

Comment: @Ramhound A power bank has a limited capacity, whereas power from the wall has not. A power bank also has some weight to it, so I can't carry unlimited power around, even if I'm willing to pay for it. I disagree that my laptop should run at the highest performance mode without my consent.